# Subreport makes a blank page

Tags: crystal-reports, report, subreport

When my subreports gets too large, Crystal Reports 14 makes the first page blank then starts printing the subreport only on the second page. How do I deal with this? My report has header, a top group, and a bottom group. The table starts on the top group and ends at the bottom group.

I've tried putting the subreport in the details section and checking 'Don't Break Object'. That gave me duplicated subreports (each duplicate per row in DB)

I also tried putting the subreport in a different section group and check/unchek 'Don't Break Object' - This leaves a blank table on first page (if row > 6) and prints all rows on the second page.

Comment: put it on report header and check result

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by turning off the "Keep Together" property of the section.

Also there are many "Keep Togethers" that can cause this to happen so I had to eliminate them all (for fields, subreport sections, subreports and groups).